# AJAX and php include

Tags: php, ajax

I have a script which loads several pages (views/home.php, views/about.php, views/contact.php etc):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#content').load('views/home.php');

$('ul#nav li a').click(function(e) {

var pageq = $(this).attr('href');
$('#content').load('views/' + pageq + '.php');

document.title = $(this).attr('rel');

//to get the ajax content and display in div with id 'content' 
$.ajax({
url:'views/'+pageq+'.php',
success: function(data){
$('#content').html(data);
}
});

//to change the browser URL to 'pageq'
if(pageq!=window.location){
window.history.pushState({path:pageq},'',pageq); 
}

return false;

});

});
```

But it works only with html, for ex. `<h1>Home</h1>`.

Now I would add some variables to this pages. For example in setup.php there's a variable $page. How to display `<h1>$page['title']</h1>` ?

I tried with `include('config/setup.php');` but it doesn't work.

I also tried this in my .js file: `$.get('config/setup.php', { x : y });`, but I don't know how to pass this variables and what is the best approach.

EDIT - navigation:

```
<?php

try{
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mysite", 'root','root');
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

?>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav">

<?php
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $sub_sql = "SELECT * FROM submenu WHERE cat_id=:id";
    $sub_stmt = $pdo->prepare($sub_sql);
    $sub_stmt->bindParam(':id',$row->id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sub_stmt->execute();

    ?>
    <li class="dropdown <?php selected($path['call_parts'][0], $row->slug, 'active') ?>"><a href="<?php echo $row->slug; ?>" rel="<?php echo $row->title; ?>"><?php echo $row->title; ?></a>
    <?php
    if($sub_stmt->rowCount()) {
        ?>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <?php

        while ($sub_row = $sub_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
            ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $sub_row->href; ?>"><?php echo $sub_row->sub_name; ?></a></li>
            <?php
            }

        ?>
        </ul>
        <?php
        }
    ?>
    </li>
    <?php
    }
?>

</ul>
```

Comment: What does it do when you have `include('config/setup.php');` in your view files? That's how it will work, you won't call the setup file through javascript.

Comment: So there is no way to load dynamic content without refreshing the pages? I always get one of those: 1) only static content and no page refresh; or 2) dynamic content and page refresh. What I want is: 3) dynamic content, no refresh :) EDIT: I could also perform db query on every page separately to get content from db. But is it the only way?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have "json" in your jQuery ajax statement

```
php:
$myVar = $_POST['myVar'];
echo json_encode(array( "var_1"=>$var1, "var_2"=>$var2 ));


javascript:
var myVar = 'xyz';
$.post('config/setup.php', { myVar:myVar }, function(data) {

        var var_1 = data.var_1,
            var_2 = data.var_2; //<< matches w/ php above

}, "json");
```

Comment: It works only if I refresh the page. That's the whole point. Whatever I try, I always get one of those: 1) only static content and no page refresh; or 2) dynamic content and page refresh. What I want is: 3) dynamic content, no refresh :)

Comment: EDIT: I could also perform db query on every page separately to get content from db. But is it the only way?

Comment: IM not understanding what you are expecting.

Comment: 1) I would like to switch between pages without reloading them. 2) I would like this pages to have some dynamic content. 3) I would also like to keep things organized - so that I don't need to make a db query on every single page.

Comment: the ajax code above will do that.  how did you envision switching the content?  a button click?

Comment: Navigation (I added the file above). I'm switching pages by clicking id="nav".

Comment: so if `clicks` initiate an ajax call, is that not enough?

Comment: No, because your code above displays only the homepage content. And when I'm switching pages it remains the same. I just noticed that firebug shows "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/mysite/config/setup.php" . I have no idea why - everything was working until I start to implement ajax.

Comment: cant you have different ajax calls per click and inject that into the dom?

Comment: I need to analyze all this mess, thanks for clues :)